# Blackberry general information

Tags: blackberry

I'm looking for documentation and information about the Blackberry OS and Blackberry Api  but the resources seem to be scarce. Is there something similar to  http://developer.android.com/index.html for Blackberry ? Or any other type of resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first stop has to be the official BlackBerry developers site at:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers

All the SDKs, lots of tutorials, docs, etc

The official forums are also useful:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Development/ct-p/BlackBerryDevelopment

And I'd recommend a good book, there are 3 for beginners that come to mind.

BlackBerry Development Fundamentals by John Wargo (good overview of the platform and different approaches to BB development):
[http://www.amazon.com/BlackBerry-Development-Fundamentals-John-Wargo/dp/0321647424/ref=dp_cp_ob_b_title_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321647424)

BlackBerry Java Application Development by Bill Foust (just came out, I haven't read it yet but it's gotten some positive feedback):
[http://www.amazon.com/BlackBerry-Java-Application-Development-Beginners/dp/1849690200/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1281984330&sr=1-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849690200)

and last but not least Beginning BlackBerry Development by me! (Java application development, seems to have gotten a good reception too):
[http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-BlackBerry-Development-Anthony-Rizk/dp/1430272252/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1281984428&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430272252)

Comment: Ha! I was looking to buy a book on Blackberry development, so I just bought yours.